# PHP query for Database update executing successfully but values are not getting updated on database table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm updating customer details by fetching the data from the html form. The PHP query for the database is getting executed but changed data is not reflected in my Database table.

PHP code:

Code to fetch data from the form

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
    if(isset($_POST['savec']))
    {
        global $con;

        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $passm=$_POST['password'];
        $pass=md5($passm);
        $cust_query="UPDATE er_customer SET customer_name='$name',customer_phone='$phone',customer_email='$email',customer_password='$pass' WHERE customer_id='c_id'";
        $excecute=mysqli_query($con,$cust_query);

        if($excecute)
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Account changes is successfull.') </script>";
        }
    }
```

Form code:

```
>    <form method="post" class="registration-form"
> action="account_settings.php" id="form_login"
> enctype="multipart/form-data">
>                       
>                   <div class="form-group">
>                         <label>Name</label>
>                            <input class="form-control"  name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo"$c_name"; ?>" required>                 
> 
>                     </div>         
>                   
>                   <div class="form-group">
>                         <label>Phone</label>
>                            <input class="form-control" name="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo"$c_phone"; ?>" required>                
> 
>                     </div>
>                   
>                   
>                   <div class="form-group">
>                         <label>Email</label>
>                            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo"$c_email"; ?>" required>                
> 
>                     </div>
>               
>                   
>                   <div class="form-group">
>                         <label>Password</label>
>                            <input class="form-control" name="password" type="text" value="" required>                       
>                     </div>
>               
>                   </br>
>                   
>                   <div class="form-group">
>                        
>                            <input type="submit" class="col-sm-3 btn btn-success" name="savec" value="Save changes" align="center" />      
> 
>                     </div>
>               
>               
>               </form>
```

Comment: I guess this is the problem: `WHERE customer_id='c_id'`

Comment: I'm fetching 'c_id' from session variable, this variable is correct I have verified it.

Comment: Looking at your comment to the answer below, think you probably mean `$c_id`. As the query stands right now, `c_id` is not a valid PHP variable. Plus, you should consider looking at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) _Prepared Statements_ to prevent your code from being an easy target for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2298301)

Answer (score 0):

**Try** changing your update query like this:

```
$cust_query="UPDATE er_customer SET customer_name=$name,customer_phone=$phone,customer_email=$email,customer_password=$pass WHERE customer_id=$c_id";
```

Make sure by debugging all variable values you are getting properly

Comment: You can mark this answer as useful, if it works for you so that it helps others as well who are facing the same problem. Thanks